# Select statement can trigger dead lock on table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, deadlock

- The SQL below is inside a MySQL stored procedure.
- The procedure run by a cron job every day once at midnight to populate report table with result.
- this procedure take around 2 min to run.
- please note that `table1` has millions of records.
- i put this to run at midnight because there are `INSERT`/`UPDATE` transactions during the day but unfortunately there are some few transaction at night also.
- when this procedure runs and if there are other transactions running then a deadlock error on `table1` occurs.

my question is

1. why `SELECT` statement cause deadlock on `table1`?
2. how can I avoid deadlock in this kind of situation?

```
DROP report;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS report AS (
    
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        
        companies.id company_id,

        (
            SELECT 
                SUM(`message_count`) single_phone
            FROM
                `table1`
            WHERE
                `table1`.`company_id` = companies.id
                AND
                `status` != 'error'
        ) AS single_phone,

        (
            SELECT 
                SUM(`message_count`)
            FROM
                `table1`
            WHERE
                `table1`.`company_id` = companies.id
                AND
                `status` != 'not error'
        ) AS log,

        (
            SELECT 
                SUM(`message_count`)
            FROM
                `table1`
            WHERE
                `table1`.`company_id` = companies.id
                AND
                `status` != 'error'
        ) AS log_monthly,

        (
            SELECT 
                SUM(`number_of_sms`) AS aggregate
            FROM
                `messages`
            WHERE
                `messages`.`company_id` = companies.id
        ) AS p_monthly
    FROM
        companies
        INNER JOIN company_users ON companies.id = company_users.company_id
    WHERE
        company_users.confirmed = 1
        AND
        company_users.deleted_at IS NULL
);
```

Comment: What makes you sure it's a deadlock and not any other kind of lock? Are you getting an error message from the MySQL server? What's in the server logs?

Comment: TIP: You can greatly improve performance by avoiding subqueries inside your top-level `SELECT`. Instead you can perform all of the aggregations in a single derived-table that you `JOIN` to. Also your use of `SELECT DISTINCT` suggests you have data-quality issues - a query like yours should not be using `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field-level queries should be done ONCE in the from clause to get pre-aggregates done ONCE per company ID and left-joined in case a given company may NOT have qualified records in a given category.  Additionally, your query to get Single_Phone is the same as your 'log_monthly', but have no criteria showing a
break or filter on the dates of activity to filter out a single month vs overall total of everything.  So, I added a where clause for filtering, but only GUESSING if such some date exists.

This query might substantially improve your performance.  By moving the COLUMN-based queries for every company ID into its own subquery via left-join, those will be summed() and grouped by company ONCE, then the JOIN for the final result.  COALESCE() is used so if no such counts exists, the value returned will be 0 instead of null

```
DROP report;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS report AS (
      SELECT
            c.id company_id,
            coalesce( PhoneSum.Msgs, 0 ) as Single_Phone,
            coalesce( PhoneLog.Msgs, 0 ) as Log,
            coalesce( MonthLog.Msgs, 0 ) as Log_Monthly,
            coalesce( SMSSummary.Aggregate, 0 ) as p_monthly
        from
            -- this will declare an in-line variable if you do need to filter by a month as a couple of your
            -- column result names infer, but have no other indicator of filtering by a given month.
            ( select @yesterday := date_sub( date(curdate()), interval -1 day ),
                    @beginOfThatMonth := date_sub( @yesterday, interval dayOfMonth( @yesterday ) -1 day ) sqlvars,
            companies c
                INNER JOIN company_users cu
                    ON m.company.id = cu.company_id
                    AND cu.confirmed = 1
                    AND cu.deleted_at IS NULL
    
                LEFT JOIN
                ( SELECT 
                        t.company_id,
                        SUM( t.message_count ) Msgs
                    FROM
                        table1 t
                            INNER JOIN company_users cu
                                ON t.company.id = cu.company_id
                                AND cu.confirmed = 1
                                AND cu.deleted_at IS NULL
                    where
                        t.status != 'error'
                    GROUP BY
                        t.company_id ) AS PhoneSum,
                    on c.id = PhoneSum.company_id
    
                LEFT JOIN
                ( SELECT 
                        t.company_id,
                        SUM( t.message_count ) Msgs
                    FROM
                        table1 t
                            INNER JOIN company_users cu
                                ON t.company.id = cu.company_id
                                AND cu.confirmed = 1
                                AND cu.deleted_at IS NULL
                    where
                        t.status != 'not error'
                    GROUP BY
                        t.company_id ) AS PhoneLog,
                    on c.id = PhoneLog.company_id
    
                LEFT JOIN
                ( SELECT 
                        t.company_id,
                        SUM( t.message_count ) Msgs
                    FROM
                        table1 t
                            INNER JOIN company_users cu
                                ON t.company.id = cu.company_id
                                AND cu.confirmed = 1
                                AND cu.deleted_at IS NULL
                    where
                            t.status != 'error'
                        -- this would only get counts of activity for current month currently active
                        -- but since you are running at night, you need the day before current
                        AND t.SomeDateFieldOnTable1 >= @beginOfThatMonth
                    GROUP BY
                        t.company_id ) AS MonthLogMsgs,
                    on c.id = MonthLogMsgs.company_id
    
                LEFT JOIN
                ( SELECT 
                        m.company_id,
                        SUM( m.number_of_sms ) aggregate
                    FROM
                        messages m
                            INNER JOIN company_users cu
                                ON m.company.id = cu.company_id
                                AND cu.confirmed = 1
                                AND cu.deleted_at IS NULL
                    where
                        m.SomeDateFieldOnMessagesTable >= @beginOfThatMonth
                    GROUP BY
                        company_id ) AS SMSSummary,
                    on c.id = SMSSummary.company_id
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks you very much for help but i have found the problem. yes this procedure cause the deadlock on table but the actual cause of the issue is that i have put ->everyMinute() in my laravel Kernal for schedule run. and there is also a cron job configured by another developer for the same that run every minute. these will run schedule every minute and that is the real cause of the deadlock problem. i have change my Kernal schedule to ->dailyAt('02:00'); now the problem is solved.